Cleaning up staging buckets for a GCP dataflow run via flex template
I am creating GCP dataflow jobs via flex template, using Cloud Build to generate templates etc.
This results in brand new buckets being created every single time. eg i have a  dataflow-staging-us-central1-bcc13063024968bf8d7e6420b45af926 which is plenty of directories
I have at least 3-4 other directories like that.
What are best practices for cleaning these buckets?
I have a Cloud Build trigger that gets activated every time there is a commit to my repo. This trigger will try to build flex templates for all the GCP jobs I have.
Perhaps what I am doing is not best practice?

When using the gcloud dataflow flex-template build to build templates, the --staging-location flag can optionally be passed to specify a bucket for holding staging files.
i.e.
gcloud dataflow flex-template build gs://template-file-gcs-path \
  --image=gcr://image-path \
  --metadata-file=/local/path/to/metadata.json \
  --sdk-language=JAVA \
  --staging-location=gs://staging-bucket

This will prevent randomly generated GCS buckets from being created on each run.
More information here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/flex-template/build
